# jquery clone method in IE wipes out select options

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, clone

I have the following code :-

```
//-- function to enable editing of content if disabled for new records --\\
function edit(e,elems)
{
  if ( e.value == "new" )
  {
    $(e).parent().parent().find(":input[readonly]").each(function(index) {
      $(this).prop('readonly',false);
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
      $(e).parent().parent().find("select[disabled]").each(function(index) {
      $(this).prop('disabled',false);
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
//-- Insert dynamic options --\\
      if ($(this).attr('name') == 'low')
      {
        var optVal = "option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']";
        var optclone = $("#affoptions").clone();
        $(optclone).find(optVal).attr("selected",true);
        $(this).html($(optclone).find("option"));
      }
      if ($(this).attr('name') == 'high')
      {
        var optVal = "option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']";
        optclone = $("#insoptions").clone();
        $(optclone).find(optVal).attr("selected",true);
        $(this).html($(optclone).find("option"));
      }
    });
    $(e).parent().parent().find(elems).focus();
  } else {
      $(e).parent().parent().find(elems).each(function(index) {
      if ( $(this).is('select') )
      {
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
      } else {
        $(this).prop('readonly',true);
      }
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    });
  }
}
```

Which works just fine in Google Chrome but doesn't work in IE 8.
Essentially I have a form with radio buttons and one of them is for new entries.  This basically enables an input text field and removes the disabled flag for select fields.
The select options have only 1 value in them when disabled. The radio button inserts all available options from a hidden div and marks the selected index value in the new options to match the single entry from the initial load.

In IE the select options are wiped out completely leaving nothing not even the initial entry.

I haven't been able to get this to work properly and assume it's a problem with the cloned element.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Craig

Comment: Just running a quick test in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YnMMk/ The reason you most likely see this problem is that when changing the selection the DOM does not changing (I only tested the fiddle in FF and it didn't). When executing `clone()` it will clone that element as it is ssen in the DOM at that time. If you want to replicate the selection you most likely need to do that as a amnual additional step or ensure the selected option is marked as such in the DOM before cloning it. Using a debugger tool, adding `selected` to an option in the DOM causes the clone to include that selection.

Comment: François
Thanks for the response but that doesn't help me.  The clone is of a hidden div containing all the options.  I want to match the option in the select against the cloned copy setting it's selected property then replacing the select options with the cloned copy.  Like I said this function works in Google Chrome and Firefox but not IE.  Something about my function IE doesn't like.  I'm at a loss as to what it might be.

Comment: Could you post the actual rendered HTML of the select/options at the time you clone them, well, just before you execute `clone()` that is? That way we might be able to replicate your current behaviour in an isolated fiddle which would make it easier to test different solutions.

Comment: I have created a simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x7yXa/ that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out eventually.  My code is fine, the problem it turns out was IE didn't like the fact that my hidden DIV with the options in it that I was cloning, was missing the SELECT tags.  Go figure.

Comment: In that case you provided IE with invalid HTML. When providing a browser with invalid HTML there is no guarantees that everything works as expected. Some browsers cope better with invalid HTML than others but all should deal the same with valid HTML. Try using http://validator.w3.org/ to validate your HTML choosing the doc type you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out eventually. 
My code is fine, the problem it turns out was IE didn't like the fact that my hidden DIV with the options in it that I was cloning, was missing the SELECT tags. Go figure.

So changing this :-

```
<div id="affoptions" class="options">
  <option value="0001">0001 | A</option>
  <option value="0002">0002 | B</option>
  <option value="*">* | All</option>
  <option value="0003">0003 | C</option>
  <option value="0004">0004 | D</option>
</div>
```

To this :-

```
<div id="affoptions" class="options">
 <select>
  <option value="0001">0001 | A</option>
  <option value="0002">0002 | B</option>
  <option value="*">* | All</option>
  <option value="0003">0003 | C</option>
  <option value="0004">0004 | D</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Resolved it.

Cheers
Craig